# Abort HttpWebRequest won't working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am using this method to get google suggest query:

```
public void GetSuggestFromGoogle(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            query = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query);
            string targetUrl = "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?ds=yt&output=toolbar&hl=en-US&q=" + query;

            UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] bytes = utf8.GetBytes(targetUrl);
            targetUrl = targetUrl.ToString();

            request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(targetUrl)) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";

            IsDownload = true;
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), request);
        }
        catch
        {
            IsDownload = false;
            failCallback();
        }


    }
```

And before i call this method i use:

```
public void CancelGoogleRequest()
    {
        if (IsDownload)
        {
            request.Abort();
            IsDownload = false;
        }
    }
```

and this is the Finish Request Method:

```
private void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse wResponse = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
            Stream stream = wResponse.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string xml = reader.ReadToEnd();

            List<string> list = this.ParseXml(xml);
            finishCallback(list);
            IsDownload = false;
        }
        catch//(Exception erere)
        {
            IsDownload = false;
            failCallback();
        }
    }
```

And my issue is with the Abort of `HttpWebRequest`, even if i am aborting request before calling a new one the `FinishWebRequest` method is execute, It is possible to cancel it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Remarks section in [HttpWebRequest.Abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.abort.aspx):

> The Abort method will synchronously execute the callback specified to
>   the BeginGetRequestStream or BeginGetResponse methods if the Abort
>   method is called while either of these operations are outstanding.

So you can't avoid the call. But you already have your `IsDownload` flag and could use it this way:

```
private void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    if (IsDownload)
    {
        // handle response
    }
}
```

when you change the Cancel method like this:

```
public void CancelGoogleRequest()
{
    if (IsDownload)
    {
        IsDownload = false; // set before Abort
        request.Abort();
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE: In case you can't use the `IsDownload` flag you could simply rely on the following (also from the Remarks):

> The Abort method cancels a request to a resource. After a request is
>   canceled, calling the GetResponse, BeginGetResponse, EndGetResponse,
>   GetRequestStream, BeginGetRequestStream, or EndGetRequestStream method
>   causes a WebException with the Status property set to RequestCanceled

As you already have a try block around your response handling code, everything should be ok. However you shouldn't set `IsDownload = false` in the exception handler when a new request has already been started, at least not when the WebException Status is `RequestCanceled`:

```
private void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        // handle response
    }
    catch (WebException webEx)
    {
        if (webEx.Status != WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
        {
            IsDownload = false;
            failCallback();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        IsDownload = false;
        failCallback();
    }

}
```

---

Another idea. As `Abort` calls the `FinishWebRequest` callback synchronously, you may use an `IsAborted` flag like this:

```
public void CancelGoogleRequest()
{
    if (IsDownload)
    {
        IsDownload = false; // set before Abort
        IsAborting = true;
        request.Abort();
        IsAborting = false;
    }
}
```

with a callback like this:

```
private void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    if (!IsAborting)
    {
        // handle response
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use the isDownload flag because when i cancel a call i call another one immediately

Comment: In which case the the WebExceptionStatusid RequestCanceled??

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.aspx): `The request was canceled, the WebRequest.Abort method was called, or an unclassifiable error occurred. This is the default value for Status`. Not very helpful, I guess...

Comment: See my edit for another approach with an additional flag that avoids relying on WebException.Status.